# Why is the overridden `add` method that JFrame defines is not mentioned in the API documentation of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

Quoting http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html :

> As a conveniance `add` and its variants, `remove` and `setLayout` have
>   been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary. This means
>   you can write:
>
> ```
> frame.add(child);
> ```
>
> And the child will be added to the contentPane.

Quoting from Core Java Volume I - Fundamentals (9th Edition), Chapter 7,
Section 7.4.

> As of Java SE 5.0, the JFrame.add method has given up trying to
>   reeducate programmers, and simply calls add on the content pane.
>
> Thus, you can simply use the call
>
> ```
> frame.add(c);
> ```

But when I scroll through the API docs at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html, I
can't find any documentation on the `add` method in JFrame that
overrides an `add` method of a parent class.

In fact, the first occurrence of any `add` method I see in this page is
in the 'Methods inherited from class java.awt.Container' section of the
page.

Why is the overridden `add` method that JFrame defines is not mentioned
in the API documentation of JFrame?

Comment: add() delegates to addImpl(), which is documented in the JFrame javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#addImpl%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29

Comment: @JBNizet Do you mean that the `add()` method is not overridden in JFrame? But it's the `addImpl()` method that is overridden instead? And the `add()` method inherited from `java.awt.Container` calls `addImpl()`? In that case, this statement from the top of [the JFrame doc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) seems to be inaccurate: `As a conveniance add and its variants, remove and setLayout have been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary.`

Comment: It's slightly inaccurate, yes. The important thing is that add() does add to the content pane. It has been overridden indirectly, by actually overriding addImpl().

Comment: I guess the point is that nobody uses the `addImpl(..)` method to add components to a container. So the effect of using the `add(...)` method that everybody knows and loves is that its behaviour has been changed. The point of the documentation is that you can still continue to use the `add(..)` method to get the new benefits. You don't need to switch to using the `addImpl(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

[`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) has not been overridden and still is inherited from [`java.awt.Container`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) but as you can see below, a call is made to `addImpl` which is overridden in [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

```
376     public Component add(Component comp) {
377         addImpl(comp, null, -1);
378         return comp;
379     }
```

---

### [`JFrame#addImpl()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#addImpl(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20int))

> Adds the specified child Component. **This method is overridden to
>   conditionally forward calls to the contentPane.** By default, children
>   are added to the contentPane instead of the frame, refer to
>   RootPaneContainer for details.